# Stream Amazon Connect audio in real time with KVS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-connect

I have a contactflow in AWS Connect with customer audio streaming enabled. I get the customer audio steam in KVS and can read bytes from the stream and convert it to an audio file when the call is completed in Java with the examples provided by AWS.
But I want to steam the audio in a web page for real-time monitoring exactly like the AWS provides real-time monitoring in built-in CCP.

I get the steam ARN and other contact data. How can I use that stream for real-time monitoring/streaming?
Any heads up will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a WebRTC client in the browser/page you want to use monitoring and controlling the the stream.  AWS provides a WebRTC SDK for Kinesis Video Streams that can be used for this. The SDK documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-js.html), which includes a [link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js) to samples and config details on GitHub

Comment: The problem with WebRTC is that there is no signaling channel available when Connect creates a stream in KVS. Can I create a channel and associate an existing stream with it? so that a WebRTC client is then configured to connect to that channel and monitor/control the stream

Comment: Yes, the SDK does this for you. You provide the stream ARN and IAM access credentials in the config for the SDK and it sets-up the WebRTC client with a control and media channel. See the GitHub sample (linked in answer) and readme.

Comment: Couldn't find an example where WebRTC client is configured with stream ARN only without signaling channel. Trying for the last many days. Could you please point me to some section?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, I thought you were asking how to create the control channel. You can’t create the WebRTC client without the control channel, and the SDK does this for you.